# JUnit4: Assert that Object has not set attributes

Tags: junit, junit4, assert

I am testing a method which should return an object of type `Card`. Something like:

```
@Test
public void testPrepareCardData() {   
   Card card = service.prepareData(ID);
```

After that I want to assert that all of the attributes of `card` **have not been set**. Let's say the method returned empty object.
One way to do it (pretty naive) is to check every attribute, like:

```
assertNull(card.getId());
assertNull(card.getCardNumber());
etc.
```

But there is **many attributes** and it would take some time.
Is there any sophisticated solution to that ?

Comment: You can use `Java Reflection` for doing that and there is a library for testing `getter` and `setter` but don't remember it name :)

Comment: @heaprc https://github.com/hazendaz/javabean-tester perhaps?

Comment: It's an option, but the one I used was different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Reflection` to perform that

```
Method[] methods = card.getClass().getDeclaredMethods();
for (Method method : methods) {
    if (method.getName().contains("get")) {
        method.setAccessible(true);
        // Act & Assert
        assertNull(method.invoke(card));
    }
}
```

More information: [Reflection Oracle doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/reflection/index.html)

Comment: this works pretty fine, thanks. but don't forget to handle exceptions, like to surround block with try-catch